# Facebook Like Button Keeps Resetting

Tags: facebook

I'm trying to add a facebook "like" button to my page, and it is appearing just fine. My problem is that once it is clicked by a user, it says "Like NUMBER" then resets as if the request was canceled or something.

The weird thing is that if I try to like a page using my facebook account it works, but I tried letting a friend like some content and this behavior appeared.

I created a facebook app, specified the site url with a trailing slash, and site domain. I used the app ID with FB.init, and with the open graph tags. I can't figure what I'm doing wrong here. Any help would be appreciated.

Sample page can be found at: http://wiseolive.com/en/doctors/3881-khalid-jamal-salaymeh

Comment: It's working just fine for me. Maybe it's a browser caching issue?!

Comment: @ifaour: After asking the question, I let other friends try it, and its working just fine for everybody except that friend that I mentioned earlier. He tried different browsers/machines, yet it just won't work for him. I can live with this situation, but would like to know what's going on, any thoughts?

Comment: That's weird. Is he trying from a limited access connection? like from his office where *maybe* Facebook is blocked?

Comment: I'm noting the same trouble over here on my own new setup. Clicking it once shows an updated count, then, in a moment or so, it resets to  the previous count (in this case, zero).

Answer (score 1):

First, for the count to work correctly, Facebook needs to have access to the page (in other words a public page).  Check your URL in the linter tool (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) to ensure it can been seen by Facebook.

Secondly, ensure your og: tags are correctly setup.  Once again, you can use the linter tool to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook like buttons will show this behavior until they have been scraped by Facebook.  That  scraping ([facebook like docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/)) will occur every 24 hours, when an admin clicks the like button or the url is put in the [url debugger/linter](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug).  From what I can tell doing that will solve the problem for that specific link, but not any others you may have on your site.

I don't know of a generic solution for dynamically generated pages unfortunately.